# Title does not appear on my D3js radar chart

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js

I am new to java script and I am trying to draw a radar chart. Everything works well except title. Can u please tell me what is wrong? I attached the code below. First I create text var and call it to show.

```
    <style>
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
    }
    #chart {
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px;
      left: 20px;
    }   
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/js/radar.js'/>"></script>
```

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="chart"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var w = 200;
    var h = 200;

    var colorscale = d3.scale.category10();

    //Legend, titles
    var LegendOptions = ['Try Count','Succcess Count', 'Success Rate'];

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////// Initiate legend ////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    var svg = d3.select('#body')
        .selectAll('svg')
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", w+300)
        .attr("height", h)

    //Create the title for the legend
var text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "title")
        .attr('transform', 'translate(90,0)') 
        .attr("x", w - 70)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("font-size", "12px")
        .attr("fill", "#404040")
        .text("What % of owners use a specific service in a week");


    //Initiate Legend   
    var legend = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("height", 100)
        .attr("width", 200)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(90,20)') 
        ;
        //Create colour squares
        legend.selectAll('rect')
          .data(LegendOptions)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", w - 65)
          .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 20;})
          .attr("width", 10)
          .attr("height", 10)
          .style("fill", function(d, i){ return colorscale(i);})
          ;
        //Create text next to squares

        legend.selectAll('text')
          .data(LegendOptions)
          .enter()
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", w - 52)
          .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 20 + 9;})
          .attr("font-size", "11px")
          .attr("fill", "#737373")
          .text(function(d) { return d; })
          ;


    //Options for the Radar chart, other than default
    var mycfg = {
      w: w,
      h: h,
      maxValue: 0.6,
      levels: 6,
      ExtraWidthX: 300
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
var svg = d3.select('#body')
    .selectAll('svg')
    .append('svg')....
```

To:

```
var svg = d3.select('#body')
    .append('svg')....
```

As you are only appending one svg, you do not need the selectAll() portion. The following takes your code and makes that one change:

```js
var w = 200;
var h = 200;

var svg = d3.select('#body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr("width", w+300)
    .attr("height", h)

var text = svg.append('g').append("text")
   .attr("class", "title")
   .attr('transform', 'translate(90,0)') 
   .attr("x", w - 70)
   .attr("y", 10)
   .attr("font-size", "12px")
   .attr("fill", "#404040")
   .text("What % of owners use a specific service in a week");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="body"></div>
```